# Styling layout with flexbox

Tags: css

How should I style using flexbox to get a layout like this? I'm hesitant to use grid as it has limited support on IE11. I'd love to make it possible to add more or less small divs and not to add more containers for small divs

HTML for the layout is looking like this:[Desired Layout image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbYvV.png)

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.large {
  height: 200px width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.small {
  height: 100px;
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="large">1</div>
  <div class="small">2</div>
  <div class="small">3</div>
  <div class="small">4</div>
  <div class="small">5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Flexbox doesn't seem the best fit for this. Have you checked out [Grid Layouts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout)? They have pretty good browser support. Edit: Oh boy, just noticed that you mentioned grids. My bad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use css-grid over flexbox, here is an example:

tutorial [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/), current specifications [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/)

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 60px 60px 60px 60px 60px;
  grid-template-rows: 30px 30px;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}
.container div {
  border:1px solid gold;
}
.item-a {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <div class="item-a">item-a</div>
  <div class="item-b">item-b</div>
  <div class="item-c">item-c</div>
  <div class="item-d">item-d</div>
  <div class="item-e">item-e</div>
</section>
```

Comment: That would be perfect, however how supported it is in IE11? caniuse.com tells that it has only partial support

Comment: @benNek IE11 global usage 2,2% and shrinking

Comment: I know, sadly for me, but it has to support IE11 :(

Comment: caniuse.com says concerning IE11 + flexbox: "Partial support is due to large amount of bugs present (see known issues)", so you might also run in some issue. AFAIK you can use css-grid for IE11, but need to write some extra CSS for it

Comment: I found this doc with some guiding for IE11: https://medium.com/@elad/supporting-css-grid-in-internet-explorer-b38669e75d66

Answer (score 1):

I added a parent div for `.small` divs and I used `margin` and `flex-wrap`. But I suggest use grid for you.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.large {
  height: 220px;
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  margin:10px;
}

.small_cont {
  width:340px;
  display:flex;
  height:200px;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.small {
  height: 100px;
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="large">1</div>
  <div class="small_cont">
    <div class="small">2</div>
    <div class="small">3</div>
    <div class="small">4</div>
    <div class="small">5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```